# Is this question inappropriate for Programmers? Can we reopen it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, close-reasons, vote-to-reopen

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187205/how-to-write-a-program-in-java-that-prints-square-of-integers-without-using-vari), which was just closed, seems appropriate to me.  My reasons:

- the asker is trying to learn about functional programming
- when reading an article about FP, the asker wasn't able to understand an example due to a key missing concept
- the intent of the question is to understand the concepts behind implementing an algorithm in FP -- not just getting some code

In short, I think it's an on-topic, valuable question (unless a duplicate exists, although I didn't find one), and I've upvoted it.

Is it an appropriate question?  If not, can it be improved to meet Programmers' standards (and how)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original phrasing was a bit not constructive. That said, I fully agree that the core question is about understanding the concepts involved, which is [what Programmers is all about](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Programmers — Stack Exchange is a site for professional programmers who are interested in getting **expert answers on conceptual questions about software development**.

Edited it a bit and re-opened. The article the question is quoting is misleading (and... stupid), but that's not the asker's fault.